# How to make one element fill to the bottom of its container in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
I have a container element which has two elements:

- A which is col-md-8
- B which is col-md-4
- C which is col-md-4

Now A is longer so it extends the container element.

I would like C to fill in the rest of the space such that height of A = height of B + height of C (including the margins).

How would I do this in bootstrap?

Comment: Your question looks similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973837/how-to-vertically-fill-a-row

Answer (score 0):

Try using **CSS Flexbox**. It will be to tidy to achieve this using bootstrap classes.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.sec-item {
  flex: 1;
}

.left-section {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 8;
}

.right-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 4;
}

.right-section .top {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.right-section .bottom {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="sec-item left-section">A</div>
  <div class="sec-item right-section">
    <div class="top">B</div>
    <div class="bottom">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It uses Flex-property

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
#leftDiv{
  height:400px;
  border:2px solid black;
}
#rightDiv{
  border:2px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.redOne{
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.greenOne{
  background-color:green;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="leftDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="rightDiv">
      <div class="redOne"></div>
      <div class="greenOne"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```